# marionette template form action not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, backbone.js, marionette

I have a simple form that I'm using as a template in a Marionette ItemView, but for some reason, when I click submit, the form action doesn't work! I know the form is submitting since form submit event works and I can get around this issue by adding in such event handlers (commented out below). However, I'd much rather just use the form action feature as that's much easier. Anyone have this issue with Marionette / Backbone?

template file:

```
<form action="/valid_route" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="text"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Marionette ItemView:

```
var View = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: template,
    //
    // ui: {
    //     form: 'form'
    // },
    //
    // triggers: {
    //     'submit @ui.form': 'submit'
    // },
    //
    // onSubmit: function () {
    //     console.log("Submit!!!")
    // },

});
```

Comment: Your form _does_ submit in a plain HTML page (because [`<button type="submit">` does submit its form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html), and there is nothing inherent to Backbone/Mn that prevents this. It's likely that another event listener matches the button click and calling `preventDefault` or `return false`.

Comment: Is the `<form>` nested in a `<form>` from another view? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms](forms shouldn't be nested).

Comment: That's not the case, I've tried testing with nothing in the Dom body but this form. :/

Comment: What browsers? It submits in the latest Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I've tried in chrome. It's weird because in chrome developer mode I can see the form without any issues in the dom. I'll post a picture later tonight.